# MySQL - Chaining multiple SQL commands

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked upon multiple threads but can't seem to find a desirable answer to my question. I am creating a system with a scheduler in it and I need multiple chains in order for the query to return an answer. So here is the scenario. A user needs to register and upon registration, the user is presented with a date.

1. I have users table where users(obviously) are listed. One column here has the date.
2. There is also a date table where the dates are stored. Each date can only occupy 30 persons.
3. The date table also has the availability column. If the date is available, it is labeled 1. If the date has expired (the current date is higher than this date), it is labeled 0.

for example, i have dates Jan 1, Jan 2 and Jan 3 and the current date is Jan 2. Obviously, Jan 1 should be expired. That wouldn't be included in the list so I will set the availability to 0 (yes, manually). There is only Jan 2 and Jan 3. I also need to find if Jan 2 has accommodated 30 people. Else, I need to put him to Jan 3. I got a bunch of parts of the codes that I don't know how to chain.

Expected Output :
query1 (Jan 2 and Jan 3 should be the result)

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE availability = 0

RoomID    Room Date    Room Availability
1         Jan 1        1
2         Jan 2        0
3         Jan 3        0
```

query2 - (count people assigned in specific rooms)

```
    SELECT COUNT(RoomAssigned) FROM users

Users        RoomAssigned
Jack         2
Eddie        2
```

query3 - (system should be able to locate the first room that is available)
    if (query2 results<30)
        put new user to rooms from result in query1

If ever the chaining I was looking for would possibly be not advisable, I am open for different suggestions. Thanks. :)

Comment: I don't understand the output of query 1. You said `WHERE availability = 0`, why is it showing rooms where `availability = 1`?

Comment: You listed two tables at the top: `users` and `date`. What is the `rooms` table in query 1?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be very confused about what tables you have and what's in them, and I don't see how your sample queries can produce the output you showed. But it seems like this query will do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms
WHERE availability = 1
AND roomID NOT IN (
    SELECT roomAssigned
    FROM users
    WHERE availability = 1
    GROUP BY roomAssigned
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30)
ORDER BY roomDate 
LIMIT 1
```

The subquery finds all the rooms that are filled, and then we exclude those from the main query. Then we sort the remaining rooms by date, and select the first one with `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want something like this:

```
SELECT  r.[RoomID],
    r.[Room Date]
FROM    rooms r
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON r.[RoomID] = u.[RoomAssigned]
WHERE   r.[Room Date] >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY r.[RoomId], r.[Room Date]
ORDER BY r.[Room Date], r.[Room Id]
HAVING COUNT(u.[RoomAssigned]) < 30
LIMIT 1
```

I haven't tested it, so it may require some tweaking. It's like @Barmar's answer, only using a join instead of a nested select. I also checked the availability based on the current date, not the `availability` column, which I don't think should be stored in the database, because it can be determined based on the Room Date.